# how to make horizontal scroll bar in select box in html

Tags: html, select, scrollbar

[image]

I want to make this scroll bar. I added overflow-y, wrapped with div, overflow : auto, set size but didn't work. Could anybody help me please?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Horizontal scrollbars are not supported in an HTML Select. However, here's a way around it:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="scroll">
<select size="6" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1" selected>option 1</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3">option 3</option>
    <option value="4">option 4</option>
    <option value="5">option 5</option>
    <option value="6">option 6</option>
</select>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
<style type="text/css">
 .scroll{
   overflow: auto;
   width: 60px;
   height: 70px;
   border: 1px silver solid;
 }
 .scroll select{
   border: none;
 }
</style>
```